# How to calcuate and add increased pay in a list

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple block of code that contains a list of salaries and the goal is to calculate a percentage increase (in this case it's 4%) and end up with the new salary listed with the increased pay. I'm able to calculate the percentage just fine, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to add this increase to the existing pay *in a list*.

Here's the code I have so far. I can figure out how to get the result I want on a single expression with one number, I'm just strugging to apply it to a list.

```
def emploee_salary():
    salary_increase = [.04 * n for n in [4100.25,
                                         4025.75,
                                         5200.00,
                                         3330.25,
                                         4420.50,
                                         2900.25,
                                         3210.00,
                                         6322.00,
                                         1125.00,
                                         1460.00]]

    print(salary_increase)


emploee_salary()

[164.01, 161.03, 208.0, 133.21, 176.82, 116.01, 128.4, 252.88, 45.0, 58.4]
```

What I want from here is to add these percentage results to the old salary to produce the new. While I'm new to Python and programming in general, I feel like the answer is likely pretty simple. But my tired brain can't seem to see it.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Multiply by `1.04` to get the increased salary. Or use `n + n * 0.04`. This is basic math, it doesn't require programming experience.

Comment: Scott, thank you for pointing that out. I attempted quite a few solutions, but just forgot to include them. I'll keep that in mind going forwar.

Comment: Barmar, thank you so much. That worked perfectly. I'm not sure why I didn't see it earlier. Programming tunnel vision I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def employee_salary():
     old_salaries = [4100.25, 4025.75, 5200.00, 3330.25, 4420.50, 2900.25, 3210.00, 6322.00, 1125.00, 1460.00]

     salary_increase = [0.04 * n for n in old_salaries]

     new_salaries = [old + increase for old, increase in zip(old_salaries, salary_increase)]

     print("Old Salaries:", old_salaries)
     print("Salary Increase:", salary_increase)
     print("New Salaries:", new_salaries)

employee_salary()
```

Old Salaries: [4100.25, 4025.75, 5200.0, 3330.25, 4420.5, 2900.25, 3210.0, 6322.0, 1125.0, 1460.0]
Salary Increase: [164.01, 161.03, 208.0, 133.21, 176.82, 116.01, 128.4, 252.88, 45.0, 58.4]
New Salaries: [4264.26, 4186.78, 5408.0, 3463.46, 4597.32, 3016.26, 3338.4, 6574.88, 1170.0, 1518.4]